# SQLAlchemy "created_at" column does not exist

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I'm building a simple application to practise a bit with fastAPI and Postgres.
I created POST to create "post" with title and content as mandatory fields.

However, I want Postgres to handle itself the "created_at_ date
Here is my post model:

```
class Post(Base):
    __tablename__ = "posts"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    title = Column(String, nullable=False)
    content = Column(String, nullable=False)
    published = Column(Boolean, default=True)
    created_at = Column(TIMESTAMP(timezone=True), nullable=False, server_default=func.now())
```

Here is my POST api:

```
@app.post("/posts", status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
def create_posts(post : Post, db : Session = Depends(get_db)):
    #new_post = models.Post(title = post.title, content = post.content, published = post.published)
    new_post = models.Post(**post.model_dump()) # nice function to avoid writiting all in case they are 50 lines
    db.add(new_post)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(new_post)
```

Here you can find my pydantic model for post

```
class Post(BaseModel):
    title : str
    content : str
    published : bool = True
```

And finally the error I get by sending my POST request via postman:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn) column posts.created_at does not exist
LINE 1: ...st ', 'test new again', true) RETURNING posts.id, posts.crea...
```

Thanks for your help !

I've tried somehow to add a date attribute in my pydantic model (I lack the syntax maybe)

Comment: you need to show the code used to create the table in the database. The SQLAlchemy model is not enough because it's just a declaration. If you are using alembic to create database migrations (revisions in the alembic jargon) or any other tool, you need to check the CREATE TABLE statement

Comment: I have added more code

Comment: Did you add the field after you ran `create_all` for the first time?

Comment: Yes I created the table first without the created_at column and tried to add it after

Comment: That's precisely the problem. The column does not exist in your database table. You need to add it.